# Excel - Combining worksheets to form a pivot

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am working in Excel and looking to make a pivot table using multiple worksheets.

I have data that is collected weekly with the same column headings and I would like to combine this into a pivot table so that I can view summaries of the data and filter by month + other headings.

I can't combine the worksheets and copy and paste to create a larger table as each worksheet contains a very large data set.

Are there any suggestions on how to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you export to sql, and perhaps handle the pivot in application code

Comment: What is the rough size of "very large" ?

Comment: When you say multiple worksheets, are these all stored within one file or are they all separate excel files?